# How to convert wrapped array to dataset in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[image]

Hi I am new to spark scala. I have this structure in json file which I need to convert it to dataset. I am being unable to do this because of the nested data.

I tried to do something like this which I got from some post but it does not work. Can someone please suggest me the solution?

```
  spark.read.json(path).map(r=>r.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("readings"))
```

Comment: can you paste a sample data here, and tell whats the expected outcome? Thanks.

Comment: the outcome is like the following format

did     d7cc   
,readings WrappedArray[WrappedArray[rssi,snRatio,cid,clientOS,ssid]],ts]

did is the column with value d7cc...
and in readings column i get these nested WrappedArray. Can u get some clue from this. 

I need to save it to dataset so that i can perform filters and joins

Comment: Don't paste the image of your data, paste the text format of your input data.

Answer (score 2):

Your `JSON` format is invalid for spark to convert into `dataframe`. `json` informations that needs to be converted into `dataframe`/`dataset` `row` should be a line.

So the first step for you to do is read the *json file* and convert into valid `json` format. You can use `wholeTextFiles` api and some replacements.

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("path to your json text file")
val validJson = rdd.map(_._2.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", ""))
```

Second step is to covert the valid `json` data into `dataframe` or `dataset`. Here I am using `dataframe`

```
val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(validJson)
```

which should give you

```
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|did                             |readings                                                                                                                                                                 |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|d7cc92c24be32d5d419af1277289313c|[[WrappedArray([aa1111111111111111c1111111111111112222222222e,AppleiOS,-46,49,ITU++], [09dfs1111111111111c1111111111111112222222222e,AppleiOS,-50,45,ITU++]),1506770544]]|
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- did: string (nullable = true)
 |-- readings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- clients: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- clientOS: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rssi: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- snRatio: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ssid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ts: long (nullable = true)
```

Now selecting `WrappedArray` is easy step as

```
dataFrame.select("readings.clients")
```

which should give you

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|clients                                                                                                                                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray([aa1111111111111111c1111111111111112222222222e,AppleiOS,-46,49,ITU++], [09dfs1111111111111c1111111111111112222222222e,AppleiOS,-50,45,ITU++])]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

`Dataframe` and `datasets` are almost the same except that `datasets` are type safety with encoders used, and that `datasets` are optimized than `dataframes`.

Long story short, you can change the `dataframe` to `dataset` by creating `case classes`. For your case you would need three `case classes`.

```
case class client(cid: String, clientOS: String, rssi: Long, snRatio: Long, ssid: String)
case class reading(clients: Array[client], ts: Long)
case class dataset(did: String, readings: Array[reading])
```

And then cast the `dataframe` to `dataset` as

```
val dataSet = sqlContext.read.json(validJson).as[dataset]
```

You should have `dataset` in your hand :)

Comment: much appreciated. Can you please show it how to do in dataset also because I need to do it in dataset. Thank you

Comment: you should be creating case class for creating a dataset.

Comment: I have updated my answer @BirajDhakal, :) Hope it answers your question completely. Why do you want dataset when dataframe is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create DataSet with the following code

```
spark.read.json(path).map(r => r.getAs[WrappedArray[String]]("readings"))
```

Check the schema of `clients` type for the DF created upon reading the JSON.

```
spark.read.json(path).printSchema

root
 |-- did: string (nullable = true)
 |-- readings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- clients: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- clientOS: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rssi: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- snRatio: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ssid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ts: long (nullable = true)
```

You can get the `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray`object with the below code

```
spark.read.json(path).first.getAs[WrappedArray[(String,String,Long,Long,String)]]("readings")
```

If you need a create the dataframe use the below.

```
spark.read.json(path).select("readings.clients")
```